# Apache2: IP rendering vhost when I don't want it to?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an Apache2 server setup with several vhosts, and it all works fine. Navigating to my ip renders one of those vhosts (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/main_site.com`), which--up until now--I had wanted.

Now I want the ip to go to the default vhost `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default`, but I can't remember where to change that. I assume there's some directive in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, but nothing is sticking out at me.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
➜ /etc/apache2: ls sites-enabled/  
default                 micro_main_1.com          micro_main_2.com            main.com
sub1.main.com           micro_main_3.biz          micro_main_4.com            main_site.com
sub1.main2.com          micro_main_5.biz
```

---

```
➜ /etc/apache2/sites-enabled: cat default
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Email

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

---

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` => https://gist.github.com/1017147

---

```
➜ /etc/apache2/sites-enabled: cat main_site.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@main_site.com
    ServerName main_site.com
    ServerAlias www.main_site.com

        # ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Naked IP ... as opposed to an IP wearing a pair of casual slacks?

Comment: can you please show your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default?

Comment: @Hyppy Haha! Yes, I only deal with pantless IPs. Standard procedure. :)

Comment: @Hameedullah Khan - Added to the post; take a look.

Comment: Eveything else looks fine, can you please also show the output of "apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have in your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

ServerName main_site
DocumentRoot /var/www

NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Move NameVirtualHost before Inlcuding virutal hosts configurations. It should be like following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

Also you don't need the NameVirtualHost * in your default virtual host file.

Answer (score 0):

The first VirtualHost that's loaded with that IP:Port pair will be used to render requests which do not contain a host header.  Make sure your virtualhosts clearly use the IP address or *, and the port #.  Now, I believe the files in sites-enabled are loaded in alphabetical order, which would mean that the default file should take precedence over the main_site file.

Post your VirtualHost and we can take a look.

Comment: Added to the post; take a look.

Comment: Stab in the dark:  Apache may prefer the more-specific default.  Your VHost in your main_site is *:80, which specifies a port, while your default is even-more-vague.  I personally specify full IP:PORT in all my VirtualHosts, but you may want to try upping the default to a matching *:80 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You've likely got a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directive that specifies the IP address in `main_site`, or the `<VirtualHost>` block specifically specifies the IP to listen on (instead of `*:80`; which is probably disabling name-based vhosting completely).

If there's no matching `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`, and the vhosts are all set to a listener specification that matches your `NameVirtualHost` directive, then the first vhost to load (alphabetically) will serve the request.  That's not happening, so one of those two things must be off.

Comment: Shane, I'm pretty sure you can use name-based virtual hosting while specifying an IP address in the VirtualHost directive, so long as you turn on name-based for that IP:Port pair with the `NameVirtualHost` directive.

Comment: Doesn't look like either of those things are happening, since all my vhosts are setup to listen on `*:80` (which matches the `NameVirtualHost` directive), and alphabetically `default` is still not loading... ??

Comment: @Kyle Absolutely - I just tend to skip over that and assume that the only `NameVirtualHost` directive that most people have set is `*:80`.  @neezer Anything in the error log that might be indicating that the `default` file isn't loading?

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer.  I *think* this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Put the site that you want to respond per default first in the list.

On Ubuntu/Debian:

```
rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/00default
```

(or another site, if you want it to be the default)